# automatically store data by delegation (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController,departmentMenuDelegate{
var deptId1: NSMutableArray = []
var deptSelectedIndexPath : NSIndexPath?
var deptSelectedProfileName : String = ""

func returnDeptId()-> NSMutableArray
{
    return deptId1
}
}

class DepartmentMenuController: UIViewController,,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{
var deptId: NSMutableArray = []

var testing : Int = 0
weak var delegate : departmentMenuDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    deptId = (delegate?.returnDeptId())!
    deptId = ["suds","sdsds"]
}
}
```

Question 1: When I add value to deptId in DepartmentMenuController, it will automatically store the value to deptId in BaseViewController. why does it happen? If I remove deptId = (delegate?.returnDeptId())!, then the problem doesn't exist

It just happen with NSMutableArray but not other types(e.g.String)

Question2: For normal case, will that happen? I am wondering is it the problem in my program

Comment: Because it passed by "reference" both are sharing the same object.

Comment: how can i pass the data manually for this case? i don't want it to be automatically

Comment: It depends what u will store in the Array, because by using `return [deptId1 copy]` u will solve the issue of modifying the array. But the objects inside the array will still be sharing the same reference. `copy` is a shallow copy

Comment: but why it doesn't happen to String or other type

Answer (score 0):

When you call the delegate, you are passing by reference. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController,departmentMenuDelegate{
  var deptId: NSMutableArray = []
  var deptSelectedIndexPath : NSIndexPath?
  var deptSelectedProfileName : String = ""

  func returnDeptId(departmentID: NSMutableArray) -> NSMutableArray {
      for i in 0..<deptId.count {
        departmentID.append(deptId[i] copy)
      }
      return departmentID
  }
}

class DepartmentMenuController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

  var deptId: NSMutableArray = []
  var testing : Int = 0
  weak var delegate : departmentMenuDelegate?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      deptId = (delegate?.returnDeptId(deptId))!
      deptId = ["suds","sdsds"]
  }
}
```

Comment: what is deptId[i] copy